# Horn equation (wave propagation in an object with a circular cross-section)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mathematical-physics, greens-functions

I have a problem with finding eigenfrequencies for wave which propagate in an object with a circular cross-section. I don't know how to start. I'll be very grateful for solution and comment or solution of very similar problem.

$G(x)\frac{∂^2u(x,t)}{∂t^2}=c^2∂_{x}(G(x)∂_{x}u(x,t))$

For horn of cross-section

$G(x)=a(x+1)^2, 0≤x≤1$

And the boundary condition

$u(0,t)=u(1,t)=0$

Comment: Separation of variables in cylindrical coordinates leads to Bessel functions! :D

Comment: I don't understand how to rewrite first equation and what gives me cross-section equation

Comment: Oooh, this his harder than I thought. The horn isn't a cylinder. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webster's  Horn equation at frequency $\omega$ is just an engineer's name for a special case of the Sturm-Liouville equation. Your case is a particularly simple example. Firstly change your independent variable  to $\xi = x+1$ so your equation becomes 
$$
\xi^2 \frac{d^2u}{d\xi^2}+2\xi  \frac{d u}{d\xi}+ \frac{\omega^2}{c^2}\xi^2 u=0.
$$
I made a mistake first time round and missed the $\xi^2$ in the last term. The solutions of the new equation involve  spherical Bessel functions $j_0(x)= (1/x)\sin x $ and $n_0(x)=-(1/x) \cos x$  where now $x= \omega \xi/c$. Take linear combinations to satisfy your BCs.

Comment: What happened with coefficient $a$? How to solve Webster's Horn equation?

Comment: "a"  drops out as it is a common factor of all terms. I told you what the solution is. It is the two $l=0$ spherical Bessel functions. I even wrote them down for you.

Comment: What has happened with "t" variable and how "ω" has been created?

Comment: You wated the eigenfrequencies. Thus I take the  time dependence $e^{i\omega t}$  as one  always does when finding eigenfrequncies.